# Compare columns from different excel files and if match occurs, append to the last column(on the same line) a status

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to start this by saying that I'm not an Excel expert so I kindly need some help.

Let's assume that I have 3 excel files: `main.xlsx`, `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx`. In all of them I have a column named `Serial Numbers`. I have to:

- lookup for all *serial numbers* in `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx` and verify if they are in `main.xlsx`.

If a serial number is find:

- on the last column of `main.xlsx`, on the same row with the *serial number* that was find write `OK + name_of_the_file_in which_it_was_found`. Else, write `NOK`. At the same time, write in `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx` `ok` or `nok` on the last column if the *serial number* was found or not.

*Mention*: `serial number` can be on different columns on `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx`

#### Example:

**main.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b      abcd        c         <-- ok,2.xlsx
b      c      1234        d         <-- ok,1.xlsx
c      d      3456        e         <-- ok,1.xlsx
d      e      4567        f         <-- NOK
e      f                  g         <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

**1.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b      1234        c          <-- OK (because is find in main)
b      c      lala        d          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
c      d      3456        e          <-- OK (because find main)
d      e      jjjj        f          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
e      f                  g          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

**2.xlsx**

```
name date serial number phone status
a      b                  c          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
b      c      abcd        d          <-- OK (because find main)
c      d      4533        e          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
d      e      jjjj        f          <-- NOK (because not find in main)
e      f                  g          <-- skip,don't write anything to status column
```

I know that I could use `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` but I'm quite unfamiliar with excel formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll use a combination of the following functions:

- `ISBLANK` to check if a cell has a value, if not we'll skip it and the resulting status will be empty.
- `VLOOKUP` to find a value in another table in another file. We could have used the `LOOKUP` function but it has its issues and `VLOOKUP` lets us specify we want an exact match.
- `ISERROR` to check if `VLOOKUP` found a match or returned an error.

In the status column of `main.xlsx` use the following formula in the first row and apply to the rest of the rows below it:

`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[2.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"NOK","ok,2.xslx"),"ok,1.xslx"))`

In the status column of `1.xslx` and `2.xlsx` use this formula in the first row and apply to the rest of the rows below it:

`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[Main.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"NOK","OK"))`

Note: The formulas refer to column C because based on the examples you gave the serial number is located there.

Comment: are you sure everything is fine with this ? I've just had a closer look and there are many fields that weren't matched even if they exist in both `main` and `1` or `2`

Comment: The problem is the next one: there might not be an exact match because in some cells might be unwanted new lines after the `serial number`

Comment: In this case I would create a new column, let's call it "Clean Serial Number", and populate it with `=CLEAN(C2)' and the same for the rest of the rows. This way you'll have a clean value without non-printable characters (like newline). Then change the above formulas to search for the clean value in the clean column of every file.

Comment: I tried it but in some cases, when I have a `serial number` in the clean column I get `N/A`. Any ideas why ?

Comment: You'll need to post some samples and maybe someone can help.