# Compare columns from different excel files and if match occurs, append to the last column a status [2]

Tags: microsoft-excel

Related to [my initial question](https://superuser.com/questions/1076220/compare-columns-from-different-excel-files-and-if-match-occurs-append-to-the-la/), I'd like to know how can I modify what [@Atzmon](https://superuser.com/a/1076311/439340) proposed in his answer, so that there won't be an exact match between the columns.

The problem that I'm facing is that in some of the cells, I might have:

`" serial number"` and in another excel just `serial number`. This case won't pass the formula and it will always return `NOK`.

#### The actual question:

What's the alternative of this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[2.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"NOK","ok,2.xslx"),"ok,1.xslx"))
```

and this one:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[Main.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"NOK","OK"))
```

What I'm interested in, is **ONLY** the `serial number` from a cell. I don't care if, for example, cell A1 from `main.xlsx`equals cell C1 from `1.xlsx` but rather if `serial number` from cell A1 is found in cell C1.

Comment: What did you try to fix it?

Comment: Well, I tried using `SEARCH` function and `FIND` but somehow it wasn't enough for what I needed. For example: `=IF(SEARCH(substring,text), "Yes", "No")`, but as you can see in the answer, I also need a `False` flag. I'm really a beginner when it comes to excel formulas. ^^

Comment: so what's a serial number? is it stored as a number or a string or a date or?

Comment: @Raystafarian It's a simple string, it's just that in some cases it might not be just the `serial number` but: `" serial number"` or `serial number\n` or so.

Comment: Oh, well you will need to use TRIM and then LEFT FIND ISNUMBER

Comment: Change the C2 in the vlookup to `"*" & TRIM(C2) & "*"`

Comment: Apparently if there's a blank space it return `OK` which is not the case. It should return an empty cell. That's my final version (note that the columns are different): `=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*" & TRIM(E2) & "*",[SALES_BNR_DTN.xlsx]All!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*" & TRIM(E2) & "*",[SALES_BNR_TK.xlsx]Sheet1!$H:$H,1,FALSE)),"NOK","OK,SALES_BNR_TK.xslx"),"OK,SALES_BNR_DTN.xslx"))`